# Drupal, conflict between Taxonomy Translation (part of i17 module) and super-select module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've enabled internazionalization for my Taxonomy vocabulary, and I've noticed that I've lost the changes made by Taxonomy super-select module (http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_super_select)

I was wondering if there is a conflict between the 2 modules.

Update. Yes there is, and they suggest to apply this patch to change the module weights:
http://drupal.org/node/364254#comment-3144146

However, I've applied the patch successfully but still I can only see the dropdown menu instead of the usual checkboxes coming with Taxonomy Super Select module.

Any tip ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, I've solved by installing the Utils module and changing module weights.